How to calculate \$R_{out}\$ in this multi-stage close loop?
The following circuit is from Chapter 13  of Analog Design Essentials written by Willy Sansen.
Calculate \$R_{out}\$ for this circuit.

The author thinks
$$L_G = g_{m1} r_{o1} g_{m2} r_{o2} \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$
$$
R_{out} = \frac{1/ g_{m3}} {LG} 
=
\frac{R_1 + R_2} {g_{m1} r_{o1} g_{m2} r_{o2} g_{m3} R_1}
$$
However, according to my analysis. My \$R_{out}\$ was different from what the author said. The following is what I have tried to do.
Add test voltage and ground \$V_{in}\$.

$$
-V_X g_{m1} + \frac{V_1 - V_X} {r_{o1}} = \frac{V_X} {R_1} + \frac{V_X - V_T} {R_2} = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac {V_X} {V_T} = \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac {V_1} {V_X} = \frac{r_{o1}} {r_{o1} \parallel \mbox{$\Large \frac{1} g_{m1}$} }
$$
$$
V_1 g_{m2} + \frac{V_2} {r_{o2}} = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac{V_2} {V_1} = 
-g_{m2} r_{o2} 
$$
$$
\begin{align*} 
\Rightarrow \frac{V_2} {V_T} 
&= 
 \frac{V_2} {V_1} \frac{V_1} {V_X} \frac {V_X} {V_T} \\
&=
-g_{m2} r_{o2} 
\frac{r_{o1}} {r_{o1} \parallel \mbox{$\Large \frac{1} g_{m1}$} }
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
\end{align*} 
$$
$$
-\frac{V_T} {r_{o3}} + (V_2 - V_T) g_{m3} + \frac{V_X - V_T} {R_2}
 = 
 - I_T
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
V_T \bigr( \frac{1} {r_{o3}} + g_{m3} + \frac{1} {R_2} +  g_{m3} g_{m2} r_{o2} 
\frac{r_{o1}} {r_{o1} \parallel \mbox{$\Large \frac{1} g_{m1}$} }
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
- \frac{R_1} {R_2 (R_1 + R_2)}
\bigr)
= 
I_T
$$
$$
\approx
V_T \bigr(  g_{m3}  +  g_{m3} g_{m2} r_{o2} 
\frac{r_{o1}} {\mbox{$\Large \frac{1} g_{m1}$} }
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
+ \frac{1} {R_1 + R_2}
\bigr)
=
I_T \\
$$
$$
\approx
V_T \biggr(  g_{m3} + g_{m3} g_{m2} r_{o2} 
g_{m1} r_{o1}
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
+ 
\mbox{$\Large \frac{1} {R_1 + R_2} $}
\biggr)
=
I_T
$$
$$
\frac{V_T} {I_T}
=
\frac{1}
{g_{m3} +  g_{m3} g_{m2} r_{o2} 
g_{m1} r_{o1}
\mbox{$ \Large \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2} $}
+ 
\mbox{$ \Large \frac{1} {R_1 + R_2} $} }\\
=
\frac{R_1 + R_2}
{g_{m3} (R_1 + R_2) +  g_{m3} g_{m2} r_{o2} 
g_{m1} r_{o1}
R_1 
+ 1 }
$$

You appear to be asking a general question (title) and answering a specific question and, doing so all within the question body so, what is your real question that requires some form of answer?

@Andyaka Is my calculation correct? Because the author seems to give a different answer

@kile - the expression as given by the author is correct. Rout for feedback with voltage sampling is always reduced by a factor (1+loop gain). For loop gain LG>>1 this factor reduces to LG. However, I must asmit that I did not go through your calculation.

This is your mistake. You forgot to include gm3. https://pasteboard.co/k1x9u8aQ6qtz.png

@internet you are right. I have now already modified it. But it is still different. I still got
$$g_{m3} (R_1 + R_2)$$ in the denominator

@kile Now I think you have the correct result. The result based on LG is an approximation but its a very good approximation to apply.

@internet Thank you for verifying my result

@LvW Could you go thorough my calculation if you have time?

@internet I think $$R_{out} = \frac{1/ g_{m3} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel \bigl( R_1 + R_2 \bigl)} {LG}$$
Do you agree with me?

@LvW I think
$$R_{out} = \frac{1/ g_{m3} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel \bigl( R_1 + R_2 \bigl)} {LG}$$
Do you agree with me?

@kile yes, and if you care about "exactness" then use  1+LG but that is still an approximation.

@kile yes I agree. However, what about LG? For my opinion, the expression for LG as given by the author (directly below the circuit diagram) is not correct.

@internet I use two port network to break the loop. Could you take a look?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716555/am-i-correct-in-solving-this-loading-in-voltage-voltage-feedback

@LvW I use two port network to break the loop. Could you take a look?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716555/am-i-correct-in-solving-this-loading-in-voltage-voltage-feedback

@kile why didn`t you break the loop at the gate of M1 or M2 (without loading problems)?

@LvW Is it the same as breaking the loop at the gate of M3? However, I wouldn't be able to calculate open loop gain and $\beta$

@kile- sorry, there was a typing error. I wrote "M1 or M2" instead of "M2 or M3". Of course, the gate of M1 is not part of the loop.

@LvW  Thank you for your correction. Do you think I break the loop correctly for loading effect? I want some expert opnion.

@kile which diagram are you referring to? In the above loop gain (LG) expression there must appear R1||(1/gm1) instewad of R1 only..

@LvW https://i.imgur.com/iSakmYB.png
See my new post.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716555/am-i-correct-in-solving-this-loading-in-voltage-voltage-feedback
