Am I correct in solving this Loading in Voltage-Voltage Feedback
The following circuit is from Chapter 13  of Analog Design Essentials written by Willy Sansen.
Calculate \$R_{out}\$ for this circuit.

Break close loop with loading effect.

$$
(V_{in} - V_X) g_{m1} + \frac{V_1 - V_X} {r_{o1}}
=
\frac{V_X} {R_1 \parallel R_2}
= 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
V_X = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
(V_{in} - V_X) g_{m1} + \frac{V_1 - V_X} {r_{o1}} = 0\\
V_{in} g_{m1} + \frac{V_1} {r_{o1}} = 0\\
\Rightarrow \frac{V_1} {V_{in}} = -g_{m1} r_{o1}
$$
$$
V_1 g_{m2} + \frac{V_2} {r_{o2}}
=
0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_2} {V_1}
=
- g_{m2} r_{o2}
$$
$$
(V_2 - V_{out}) g_{m3} - \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o3}} 
= 
\frac{V_{out}} {R_1 + R_2}\\[1.0em]
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
V_2 g_{m3} = V_{out} g_{m3} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o3}} + \frac{V_{out}} {R_1 + R_2}\\[2.0em] 
V_2 g_{m3} = \frac{V_{out}} {\mbox{$\Large  \frac{1} {g_{m3}}$} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel (R_1 + R_2)} \\[2.9em] 
\frac{V_{out}} {V_2} = g_{m3} \left( \frac{1} {g_{m3}} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \right) \\[1em]
$$
$$
A_{OL}
=
\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} \\[1.5em]
=
\frac{V_{out}} {V_2} 
\frac{V_2} {V_1}
\frac{V_1} {V_{in}}\\[1.5em]
=
g_{m3} \left( \frac{1} {g_{m3}} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel (R_1 + R_2)  \right)
g_{m2} r_{o2}
g_{m1} r_{o1}\\
 \approx
g_{m2} r_{o2}
g_{m1} r_{o1}
$$
Calculate \$\beta\$ in two port network.

$$
\beta = 
g_{21} = \frac{V_2} {V_1} \bigg |_{I_2 = 0}
=
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
LG = 
A_{OL} \beta
=
g_{m2} r_{o2}
g_{m1} r_{o1}
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$

$$
-V_X g_{m1} + \frac{V_1 - V_X} {r_{o1}} =  \frac{V_X} {R_1 \parallel R_2}
= 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
V_X = 0,
V_1 = 0
$$
$$
V_1 g_{m2} + \frac{V_2} {r_{o2}} = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_2} {V_1} 
=
-g_{m2} r_{o2}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
V_2 = 0
$$
$$
(V_2 - V_{in}) g_{m3} - \frac{V_T} {r_{o1}} + I_T =  \frac{V_T} {R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
V_2 g_{m3} +  I_T = 
V_T \biggl( g_{m3} + \frac{1} {r_{o3}} +  \frac{1} {R_1 + R_2} \biggl)\\
\Rightarrow
I_T = 
V_T \biggl( g_{m3} + \frac{1} {r_{o3}} + \frac{1} {R_1 + R_2} \biggl)\\
R_{out, OL} = \frac{V_T} {I_T}\\
= \frac{1} {g_{m3}} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel \bigl(R_1 + R_2\bigl)
$$
$$
R_{out, CL} = \frac{R_{out, OL}} {1 + LG}\\
=
\frac{
\mbox{$\Large  \frac{1} {g_{m3}} $} \parallel r_{o3} \parallel \bigl(R_1 + R_2\bigl) 
}
{
1 +
g_{m2} r_{o2}
g_{m1} r_{o1}
\mbox{$\Large  \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$}
}
$$
LvW suggested we should break at the gate of either M2 or M3.


$$
- V_X g_{m1} + \frac{V_F - V_X} {r_{o1}}
=
0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_F} {V_X}
=
1 + g_{m1} r_{o1}
$$
$$
\frac{V_X} {V_T}
=
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
\frac{V_F} {V_T}
=
\frac{V_F} {V_X}
\frac{V_X} {V_T}
=
\bigl( 1 + g_{m1} r_{o1} \bigl)
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@VoltageSpike Latex can't be displayed correctly in the chat
